# Firefox (3.6.3 Mac) fails to float left the last of a set of left-floated list items

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a set of <li> elements in an unordered list. The items are all floated left, with a bit of space between them. Problem is, the last list item is wrapped (isn't at the end of the list, but leftmost on a new line). I have no idea why. The rendering is fine with Mac Safari and with IE 7.

The CSS for the li items floats them left:

```
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 1px 1px 0 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
border: 1px solid #2A3139;  /* to hold space for hover border */
```

Another factoid: the unordered list is in a div (for clipping purposes; the list is scrolled horizontally); the CSS for the <ul> specifies:

```
overflow: none;
position: relative;
```

(though I don't think this is related to the problem... but one never knows)

Comment: oops, bad CSS: I fixed the "overflow" to be "overflow: hidden" ... but that didn't fix the problem

Comment: if this is a navigation bar and you are going to have drop down menus for each item, then you need to play around with the positioning, otherwise you don't need to set a position, Also you only need to apply the "list-style:none" to the "ul" tag and not the "li".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the width of your container div wide enough to accommodate the width of all your `li` elements PLUS their margins and borders? If not, the floats will wrap to the next line if there is not enough space.

Comment: Yes, I compute the width, accounting for margins, padding, and border. But I sensed you were on to something, and so I added some fudge factor -- adding 2 pixels made this work for Firefox (it rendered properly without the fudge factor on Safari and IE). 

(btw: it is the containing list (OL/UL) element, not div, that needs this)